# Question on virtual operator* on C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, operator-overloading, virtual

I was trying to make virtual operator on C++

```
class Data
{
    virtual Matrix operator* (Matrix &_matrix);
    virtual Scalar operator* (Scalar &_scalar);
};

class Matrix : public Data
{
private:
    vector<vector<double>> data;
public:
    // ...
    Matrix operator* (Matrix &_matrix);
};

class Scalar : public Data
{
private:
    double data;
public:
    // ...
    Scalar operator* (Scalar &_scalar);
};
```

And the problem was, when I created Data* Array like below

```
Data* arr[10];
arr[0] = new Matrix(3,3);
arr[1] = new Matrix(3,3);

arr[0]->operator*(arr[1]);
```

I could not do multiplication between these two matrices, since I cannot pass Data as an argument.
But the problem is, I cannot make the function's argument to take Data* type because, it will not be able to access private members of Matrix or Scalar objects.

How to deal with this kind of weird situation?

Comment: Will you only know at runtime if you're dealing with Matrices or Scalars? Or will you know your math expressions at compile time?

Comment: This will be tricky. But note that the return type of these operators should be `Data*`, since the compiler can't know at compile time whether the result will be a `Matrix` or a `Scalar`.

Comment: [ After ruminating on this a bit, I have some comment on the approach. ] 

For my money, the basis of a good API is that the explcit and implicit semantics should match behaviour. If use operators then that means the semantics must be the same as with built in types. this means `operator*` is return by value. For covariant return types this is not possible. It follows you cannot have a double dispatch `operator*` with clean semantics. I'd recommend either using explicit method names or stick with only defining `operator*=`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Class double dispatch problem - See Meyer's (forget which one).
You need the operator to be virtual on both the lhs and rhs, so you need two virtual calls:

```
class Matrix;
class Scalar;

class Data
{
public:
    virtual Data* operator* (Data& data) = 0;
    virtual Data* operator* (Matrix &matrix) = 0;
    virtual Data* operator* (Scalar &scalar) = 0;
};

class Matrix : public Data
{
private:
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> data;

    // ...
public:
    Matrix* operator* (Matrix &_matrix)
    {
        // implement
    }
    Matrix* operator* (Scalar& scalar)
    {
        // implement
    }
    Data* operator* (Data &data)
    {
        // Magic here - *this is now Matrix, not Data
        return data * (*this);
    }
};

class Scalar : public Data
{
private:
    double data;
public:
    // ...
    Data* operator* (Data& data)
    {
        // Magic here - *this is now Scalar, not Data
        return data * (*this);
    }
    Scalar* operator* (Scalar &scalar)
    {
        // implement
    }

    Matrix* operator* (Matrix &matrix)
    {
        // Note how we need to allow for parameter reveral during the double dispatch
        Matrix& lhs = matrix;
        Matrix& rhs = *this;
        // Compute matrix product lhs * rhs
    }

};
```

I've glossed over the issue of the return type and memory management. As usual with operators, you might be better defining `*=` as the primitive. This can then return a reference to `*this`. The `*` operator can then defined in terms of `*=`. Once again, this is in "Effective C++".

Comment: D'oh ... you beat me by like a minute

Comment: Correct in general but in the specific you need a slightly different solution because matrix multiplication does not commute (i.e. you can't just reverse the arguments to get the type info you need).

Comment: @Ben Jackson. +1. Absolutely right - can't believe I didn't consider that. But re-examining, I think this is not much of an issue. It only applies to the Matrix * Matrix case, which does require careful interpretation of the terms to catch this - editing to do so.

Answer (score 4):

The solution to this is called [Double Dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch) which is a little strange in C++.  The following code shows how this trick works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <vector>


class Matrix;
class Scalar;

class Data {
public:
    virtual ~Data() {}
    virtual Data const& operator* (Data const& other) const = 0;
    virtual Data const& multiplyBy (Data const& other) const {
        throw std::runtime_error("bad function call");
    }
    virtual Data const& multiplyBy (Matrix const& other) const = 0;
    virtual Data const& multiplyBy (Scalar const& other) const = 0;
};

class Matrix : public Data {
private:
    std::vector< std::vector<double> > data;
public:
    virtual Data const& operator* (Data const& other) const {
        return other.multiplyBy(*this);
    }
    virtual Data const& multiplyBy (Matrix const& other) const {
        std::cout << "Matrix * Matrix" << std::endl;
        return *this;
    }
    virtual Data const& multiplyBy (Scalar const& other) const {
        std::cout << "Matrix * Scalar" << std::endl;
        return *this;
    }
};

class Scalar : public Data {
private:
    double data;
public:
    virtual Data const& operator* (Data const& other) const {
        return other.multiplyBy(*this);
    }
    virtual Data const& multiplyBy (Matrix const& other) const {
        std::cout << "Scalar * Matrix" << std::endl;
        return *this;
    }
    virtual Data const& multiplyBy (Scalar const& other) const {
        std::cout << "Scalar * Scalar" << std::endl;
        return *this;
    }
};

int
main() {
    Matrix m;
    Scalar s;
    Data* ary[] = { &m, &s };
    m * s;
    s * m;
    *(ary[0]) * *(ary[1]);
    *(ary[1]) * *(ary[0]);
    return 0;
}
```